# How do I return the values and variables from non main method to main method?

Tags: java

Im trying to make this program work but im getting the error that it cant find the variable min and max in the system.out.print statement in main method. I guess it is because main doesnt know what those variables are since the MinMax destroys those variables once its ran. But how can I transfer the results over from my MinMax method so that results will be printed in system.out.print in main method statement?

```
class MethodMinMaxWithUnlimitedValues {

  public static void main(String[]args) {

    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    int value;
    char choice;

    do{
      System.out.print ( " enter value " );
      value = console.nextInt();

      isMinMax(value);

      System.out.print ("enter more numbers? (y/n) ");
      choice = console.next().charAt(0);
    }

    while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

    System.out.print("min value is = " + min + " max value is = " + max);
  }

  public static void isMinMax (int n) {

    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      if (n > max) {
        max = n;

      } else if (n < min) {
        min = n;
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Many ways, you can make min max as static variables or you can return these values as part of some data structure or you can return a object of a class which contains two members min max

Comment: You can try to move your min and max variable outside the method making them static instance variables.

Comment: @pdrersin would that look something like this; class MethodMinMaxWithUnlimitedValues{ public int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;     public int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;?

Comment: Somebody below did exactly what I meant. You can check that answer out.

Comment: you have to make them static as well because you are calling them in a static method

Comment: I am assuming you know the difference between static and instance variables.

Comment: no i dont know the diff sorry hehe

Comment: @Adnan I see, so now theyre static, but the results that get returned from running the program is min value is -2147483648 max value is = 2147483647. How can I solve that?? like where in the code is the issue?

Comment: The logic in isMinMax is completely backward, you should review that code and change it.

Comment: @Zerenity you are getting these values as you are initializing as Integer.MaxValue , Integer .MinValue , since these are the extreme values an integer can hold , kindly check your logic as any integer value can't be greater than Integer.Maxvalue

Comment: hmm its weird because I have another program that works without seperate methods (all are in main), yet I have the same if else scenario

Comment: @Adnan but why arent they getting overwritten as the isMinMax method is complete?

Comment: I have something wrong somewhere which I dont see where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them `static` and global

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MethodMinMaxWithUnlimitedValues {

    static int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    static int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

        int value;
        char choice;

        do{
            System.out.print ( " enter value " );
            value = console.nextInt();

            isMinMax(value);

            System.out.print ("enter more numbers? (y/n) ");
            choice = console.next().charAt(0);
        }

        while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

        System.out.print("min value is = " + min + " max value is = " + max);
    }

    public static void isMinMax (int n) {

        if (n > max) {
            max = n;

        } else if (n < min) {
            min = n;
        }

    }
}
```

**NOTE:** that can have side effects

Comment: Thanks!!! and oh, hey, when i run the code, the desired result doesnt appear. whenever i enter a value, no matter how many, the min becomes -2147483648 whilst the max becomes 2147483647. how can i fix this issue?

Comment: This is due to your logic in the method

Comment: To see the changes you have to either type very large numbers (greater then 2147483647) or very small numbers (lower then -2147483648)

Comment: If you type e.g. 3 then nothing changes, because 3 is not larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and not smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: I see, but maybe I have something wrong in my minmax method. on question 12 http://www.beginwithjava.com/java/loops/questions.html the min max thing seems to work. Im trying to implement this but want to create a method to see if its a min value or max value